# OLEDB connection to Access not working; "Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

Tags: asp.net, ms-access

I am trying to retreive data from the Access Database from my ASP.Net application.
It works when I access one table for an ExecuteScalar.
but in the following code I get this error;
Data source name not found and no default driver specified

```
private static string GetConnectionString()
{

    string importFolder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataPath"].ToString());
    string fileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataFile"].ToString();
    return "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + importFolder + fileName; 
}

public DataTable getaddresses(string doorno, string Addsearch)
{

    System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection conn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(GetConnectionString());

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM Address_tble";
   System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter da = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter(query, conn);
    da.Fill(dt);
    da.Dispose();
    return dt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't it need to be an OLEDBConnection not ODBC? You are using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0

Comment: Or if it is suppose to be an ODBC connection, change the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to use the OleDbConnection and OleDbDataAdapter as has been suggested.

Try hard coding the path and filename in or output what the GetConnectionString() function returns. I suspect an incorrect format. Get it working first, then if that is the issue, debug the GetConnectionString() function.